# Multirow and decimal alignement

Tags: tables, multirow

Here's my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{5}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c l l c |d{5}|d{1}|d{5}|}
\toprule
\bfseries i &
\bfseries Component &
\bfseries Category &
$N_i$ &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ $\lambda_b$ } &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ $\pi_Q$ } &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ $\lambda_i$ } \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-7}
1 & MCU & Microprocessors & 1 & .048 & 10 & .48 \\
2 & MCU Socket & IC Sockets & 1 & .0035 & 0.3 & .00105 \\
3 & Ceramic capacitor & Capacitors & 2 & .0017 & 3 & .0102 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ $\lambda_{EQUIP}$ } & \multicolumn{1}{d{1}|}{ \multirow{2}{*}{0.491} } \\
\multicolumn{4}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ [Failures/$10^6$ h] } & \\
\cmidrule{5-7}
\multicolumn{4}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \bfseries MTBF } & \multirow{2}{*}{2.037} \\
\multicolumn{4}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ [$10^6$ h] } & \\
\cmidrule{5-7}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Premise: I inserted vertical lines just to better see horizontal spacing.

I'm trying to solve these problems:

- I would like to define a 2nd column type with 1 decimal for the 6th column, but I haven't found exhaustive documentation about \newcolumntype
- Why lambda_EQUIP and MTBF values aren't aligned to the decimal point? Is it a multirow issue? I tried to encapsulate lambda_EQUIP in a multicolumn aligned to the decimal point, without success as you can see.
- Suggestions for horizontal lines? Should I replace \midrule with \bottomrule?
  Exists something like \bottomrule{5-7}?

Comment: Have you tried `siunitx` package and the `s` column type?

Comment: I assume that the instruction `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{5}}` is a typo; don't you want `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}`? If not, you'll always get space reserved for five decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean with *1 decimal for the sixth column*, as the values are integers. For the rest, one can fulfill your requirements using the `numprint`  and `makecell` packages. The last mentioned is used in place of `multirow` since it allows multilined cells in tabulars with predefined formatting. I also defined a `cbottomrule` command which displays as you want, and also a `\ctoprule` that you don't need here, but that might be useful.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*\cbottomrule[1]{\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#1}\addlinespace}
\newcommand*\ctoprule[1]{\addlinespace\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{#1}}

\usepackage{numprint}%
\npdecimalsign{.}
\npthousandsep{,}
\npthousandthpartsep{\,}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\boldmath}}
\newcommand\twocolcell[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{c l  lc n{1}{4} n{2}{1} n{1}{5} }%
\toprule
\thead{i}&
 \thead{Component} &
\thead{Category} &
\thead{$N_i$} &
{\thead{$\lambda_b$}} &%
{\thead{ $\pi_Q$ }} &
{\thead{$\lambda_i$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-7}
1 & MCU & Microprocessors & 1 & .048 & 10 & .48 \\
2 & MCU Socket & IC Sockets & 1 & .0035 & 0.3 & .00105 \\
3 & Ceramic capacitor & Capacitors & 2 & .0017 & 3 & .0102 \\
\midrule
& &  &  & \twocolcell{{\boldmath$\lambda_\textbf{\itshape\scriptsize EQUIP}$} \\{[Failures/$10^6$\,h]}}  & 0.491 \\
\cmidrule{5-7}
 &  &  &  &  \twocolcell{\bfseries MTBF\\{[$10^6$\,h]}} & 2.037 \\
\cbottomrule{5-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the vertical lines (code was slighly different):
[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard!
It looks exactly as I thought!
I haven't explained well the thing about the 6th column, but I was looking for something like n{x}{y}, thanks a lot!